# How is execve invoked on linux?

Tags: linux, exec, glibc

If you call `exec(...)` on linux, it ends up calling `execve()` which calls `sys_execve()`, which then calls `do_execve`, which then walks through a list of handlers until it finds one that matches (there is a default elf handler in `binfmt_elf.c` for this).

On the other hand, if you look at the source for glibc, then `execve()` calls `hurd_exec()`, which then calls `__file_exec` (which I can't find the source for).   It looks to eventually end up in `dl-open.c`, but I can't find the code that runs in between.

I'm assuming that a userspace program will always call the version from the library, in which case, where does `__file_exec` go to?  I can't find a reference to it in either the kernel or the glibc code...

note: this is for armv8, linux 3.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand, if you look at the source for glibc, then execve() calls hurd_exec()

Not on Linux, it doesn't.

You are probably looking at `sysdeps/mach/hurd/execve.c`, but on Linux you should be looking at `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/execve.c`, which calls `INLINE_SYSCALL (execve, ...);` which does what you'd expect: pass control to the kernel.

Comment: Ahhh, that explains some things.  Thank you for getting me off the wrong path!